# Rotate rectangle bitmap in Android

Tags: android, android-image

I have a rectangle-shaped Bitmap, which I need to rotate it by 90 degrees clockwise or counter-clockwise.

I can do the rotation using this code:

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(90, originalBitmap.getWidth()/2, originalBitmap.getHeight()/2);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

However, this code rotates image "in-place" using old values for height/width. And the resulting image looks stretched and ugly.

Is there any good way to rotate the image by 90 degrees into new height/width? Probably, one possible solution is to modify dimensions of the original bitmap first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't you use old values while creating new bitmap? Just replace them in the last line:

```
 return Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth()/2, originalBitmap.getHeight()/2, matrix, true);
```

Comment: If I create the new bitmap with such params:
    newWidth = originalHeight;
    newHeight = originalWidth;
there is an exception telling me that height of the bitmap cannot be less than original.